# error: declaration of '<...>'. Strange compiler errors

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-errors, declaration

Please help me to understand gcc compiler output. I'm totally confused.

I have an error:

```
C/types.h:47:56: error: declaration of 
'struct VV::MM<VV::SSS::Vector<short unsigned int>, 8u, 0u>'
```

which already sounds strange to me.

In the types.h:47 I see:

```
template<typename V, size_t Size1, size_t Size2> class MM;
```

Which is looks ok for me.

This is second error message in the build log and I wonder can it be just a second part of the first error? Here first and the second errors together:

```
<... compiles normally, no errors ...>

In file included from A/T.h:14:0,
                 from B/I.h:5,
                 from B/F.cxx:54:
A/AArray.h: In instantiation of 
'AInternal::AlignedData<VV::MM<VV::SSS::Vector<short unsigned int>, 8u, 0u>, 104u, 0>':
A/AArray.h:561:125:   instantiated from 
'AFArray<VV::MM<VV::SSS::Vector<short unsigned int>, 8u, 0u>, AArraySize<104u> >'
A/V.h:73:99:   instantiated from here
A/AArray.h:364:20: error: 'AInternal::AlignedData<T, Size, 0>::fArray' 
  has incomplete type

C/types.h:47:56: error: declaration of 
'struct VV::MM<VV::SSS::Vector<short unsigned int>, 8u, 0u>'

In file included from <...other errors...>
```

at A/V.h:73 I have:

```
 AFArray<VV::SSS::Vector<short unsigned int>::MM, AAArraySize<N> > fAlpha;
```

which I believe can trigger second line in the log:

```
A/AArray.h: In instantiation of 
'AInternal::AlignedData<VV::MM<VV::SSS::Vector<short unsigned int>, 8u, 0u>, 104u, 0>':
```

because VV::SSS::Vector::MM is undefined type, because of the second error.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is the second error message a part of the first error?
2. What can be wrong with this declaration?

Comment: Paste all surround code lines from types.h into your question (specifically, the half-dozen or so lines immediately around line 47 of types.h, including that line).

Comment: Read error messages top-down. Fix each one of them independently. After the compiler encounters an error it tries the best it can to recover and continue, but the language is context sensitive, and it might not be able to recover correctly, so take the second and further error messages with a pinch of salt.

Comment: In gcc, the first error block goes from the first `In file included from` to the second `In file included from`. In this block, the first occurence of `error:` or `warning:` is where the compiler complains. Above it you find why gcc is even looking at that file, what it was doing at the moment (which function it is compiling, or in your case which template is instantiated), followed by why it needs to do that. Below `error:` comes a dump of what might be useful depending on the situation, e.g. what function definitions are availabe (`note:`) and possibly why they don't fit (`error:`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I lost the file with description of the defined MM class. Ones the file has been found and added to include path the errors disappeared.

The answer to my questions:

> Is the second error message a part of the first error?

Yes. It looks so.

> What can be wrong with this declaration?

Nothing is wrong, compiler just tells that the related to the error declaration is there.